# How to set date criteria from a cell in a QUERY() formula in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I use a google sheet cell as reference instead of `todate(now))`?

```
=QUERY('Task Data'!A:M,"select C, D, E, F, H, B, L, M where D < todate(now()) and G matches false")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=QUERY('Task Data'!A:M,"select C, D, E, F, H, B, L, M where D < date '"&text(N1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and G matches false")
```

[image]